# How to keep the variable value same in concatenation in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying below code in powershell and want to concatenate this. I am able to do only the issue is it is removing  { } from the variable

```
$var1 = "{\"1234-TEST-NICE\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\"}"
$var2 = "{\"1234-NCPT-NOT\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\"}"
$var3 = "{\"123478-NCP-POT\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\"}"
$var4 = "{\"1234-RICE-MICE\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\"}"

# Check variables and concatenate the true ones
$result = @()
if ($var1) { $result += $var1 }
if ($var2) { $result += $var2 }
if ($var3) { $result += $var3 }
if ($var4) { $result += $var4 }

# Join the array into a single string
$resultString = $result -join ''

# Display the concatenated result
Write-Output $resultString
```

Getting value

```
\"1234-TEST-NICE\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\",\"1234-NCPT-NOT\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\",\"123478-NCP-POT\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\",\"1234-RICE-MICE\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\"
```

Expected value:

```
{\"1234-TEST-NICE\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\"},{\"1234-NCPT-NOT\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\"},{\"123478-NCP-POT\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\"},{\"1234-RICE-MICE\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\"}
```

Comment: I'm surprised you get any output at all - `"{\"1234-TEST-NICE\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\"}"` is not valid syntax for a string literal. Please post the _exact_ code you're running

Comment: the outer double quotes on each string have to be a single quote instead, then the code works

Comment: Yes, actually thats all @SantiagoSquarzon

Comment: to be clear: you need `$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)` being LITERAL, and not values, right?     

If so, you just need to switch the outer quotes to single quotes, like @SantiagoSquarzon wrote.    

Otherwise there is more work to do and we need to know about $BuildNumber and $BranchName   

In general, though, you might want to use `$result = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()` and `$result.add($varToAdd)`.
This because ArrayLists are generally better than regular arrays in most situation except with small static arrays that not get modified

Comment: If you wanted the $Buildnumber and $BranchName variables to be interpolated, you would use a GRAVE ACCENT (backtick) to escape the QUOTATION MARK characters. `$var1 = "{\`"1234-TEST-NICE\`":\`"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\`"`

Answer (score 1):

you need to single quote the variables :

```
$var1 = '{\"1234-TEST-NICE\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\"}'
$var2 = '{\"1234-NCPT-NOT\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\"}'
$var3 = '{\"123478-NCP-POT\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\"}'
$var4 = '{\"1234-RICE-MICE\":\"$(Buildnumber)-$(BranchName)\"}'

# Check variables and concatenate the true ones
$result = @()
if ($var1) { $result += $var1 }
if ($var2) { $result += $var2 }
if ($var3) { $result += $var3 }
if ($var4) { $result += $var4 }

# Join the array into a single string
$resultString = $result -join ''

# Display the concatenated result
Write-Output $resultString
```